# What language is used to program Google and Gmail

Tags: programming-languages, gmail

I want to know what language is used to program Google and Gmail is it python or Java or what exactly is running at their core from programming languages part?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what server side language is gmail written in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525199/what-server-side-language-is-gmail-written-in)

Answer (score -7, accepted):

.NET, C++, and java

Source: http://mirnazim.wordpress.com/2006/06/16/what-language-is-google-written/

Comment: Source is dead, and 5 years older than the answer.

Comment: Google today has GWT, AngularJS and the google official languages are Java, C++, Python and Javascript.

.NET is awesome and has its own pros and cons like any other language but used by microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

Google's official languages are Java, Python, C++ and JavaScript I believe.

I would be amazed if they are using .NET in any serious capacity.